# Fedora 12 XFCE mount permissions

Tags: permissions, mount, fedora, fedora-12, xfce

I installed Fedora 12 with XFCE.

When I run Gigolo to mount Windows partitions, I get an *"Authentication is required"* message.

In Fedora 11 XFCE, there was a tool that changed the system permission to allow any user to mount any partition, but I can't find it in Fedora 12.

How can I fix this problem and set all permissions needed?

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately the PolicyKit configuration tool has been removed. The new method for configuring PolicyKit is described in the `pklocalauthority(8)` man page.

**EDIT:**

As an example, here's the contents of my `/var/lib/polkit-1/localauthority/20-org.d/vmm.pkla` file:

```
[Virtual Machine Manager]
Identity=unix-user:ignacio
Action=org.libvirt.unix.manage
ResultActive=yes
```

This allows the "unix" user `ignacio` (this would be my login) to always be allowed the `org.libvirt.unix.manage` permissions (this can be gleaned from the PolicyKit dialog box) whenever they have the active console. This allows me to run Virtual Machine Manager without having to type in root's password.

Comment: [man pklocalauthority](http://man.he.net/man8/pklocalauthority) ... Ignacio, do you have any suggestions as to what needs to be configured where?

Comment: @quack: I've updated it with an actual file on my system.